# How can I run akka-sample-distributed-data-scala demo

Tags: scala, akka

The code is from this repository: https://github.com/akka/akka-samples/tree/2.5/akka-sample-distributed-data-scala

```
➜  akka-sample-distributed-data-scala git:(2.5) ✗ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /Volumes/Macintosh HD/github/akka-samples/akka-sample-distributed-data-scala/project
 [info] Set current project to akka-sample-distributed-data-scala (in build file:/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/github/akka-samples/akka-sample-distributed-data-scala/)
 [info] Updating {file:/Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/github/akka-samples/akka-sample-distributed-data-scala/}akka-sample-distributed-data-scala...
 [info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.5 ...
 [info] Done updating.
 [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Volumes/Macintosh HD/github/akka-samples/akka-sample-distributed-data-scala/target/scala-2.12/classes...java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
 [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
 [error] (compile:run) No main class detected.
 [error] Total time: 6 s, completed 2018-5-27 10:07:14
```

It seems I run in a wrong way, how can I run it?

Answer (score 2):

So I think it's an example that you need to add to your project. So you can't run it because as console tell you "No main class detected". This example contains code and you can go through it and learn.

So if you want to run it, you need to create an object with the main method and inside main, you can use everything from another part of the project.

Here you can see that everything is okay with code because compilation finished correctly.

Here you can find more information about this library:

https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/distributed-data.html?language=scala